# Posting Data to a database through javascript Ajax which calls a php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

So basically I want to have a Javascript function that posts data to a table in my database. i know that I need to call a php page to do this. But the code I have written doesn't work. The js fucntion is triggered by a button press in html. I need to do this in js ajax and not jquery ajax

The Javascript

```
function comment_sub(){
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
    {    
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "static/setcomments.php", true);
xhttp.send(encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('comment-textbox').value));  
}
```

The PHP

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
$mydb = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","", "website");
if (!$mydb){
    die("Connection failed".mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'comments'('comment_text') VALUES ('{$_GET['comment-textbox']}')";
$query = mysqli_query($mydb, $sql);
if (!$query)
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added"
?>
```

Checked the network and console log. The JS function is being called fine but the network logs gives me a 404 error for the post request

Comment: what is your error ?

Comment: dont get an error it just doesnt do anything

Comment: call your php script with your browser and check the logs output it give you. Moreover your code is vulnerable to **sql injection** and **XSS attack**

Comment: The first step to debugging AJAX is to determine if the error is in your JS or your server side code. Just stick a `die('PHP HERE');` at the top of your PHP file, and a `console.log('JS HERE');` at the top of your AJAX function, and then open up your browser dev tools and watch the console as you do the thing that should trigger your JS. See what appears

Comment: Very vulnerable code. please view the sql query you are building before executing, see if it is correct, anyway, i dont see you sending a GET with comment-textbox , change your call to a get (and setting that variable) or your listener into post (and send that exact variable)

Comment: ok so i added the two statements in their correct files. the php doesnt ever get triggered but the js console.log works

Comment: ps i know it is vulnerable i just wanna leran how to do it like this first

Comment: If you have not, turn on your developer tools in your browser (use Chrome if your browser doesn't do this), and then look to both the console and network tabs for helpful information about why it may not be doing anything.

Comment: so i took a look at the network tab it says 404 for the post request

Comment: Is it correct `static/setcomments.php` or this `/static/setcomments.php`?

Comment: yeah @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez its right

Answer (score 0):

You are only sending the value itself, not the name `comment-textbox`.

Try this:

```
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
    'comment-textbox': document.getElementById('comment-textbox').value
}));
```

Comment: Tried no difference :(

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP page, you are doing a HTTP POST and not a HTTP GET. So rewrite it as this:

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'comments'('comment_text') VALUES ('{$_POST['comment-textbox']}')";

Comment: Rewrote it. still no change